# What limitations exist for a candidate to claim party membership if they're not an official member?

Tags: united-states, parties

For example, if Donald Trump lost a primary in 2024, he could still run for president.  If so, he might theoretically want to appeal to Republican voters by claiming to be "the *real* republican candidate" and accusing the official candidate of being a "[RINO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_in_Name_Only)."  What limitations would he face in executing such a campaign?  Can a candidate run as a party X candidate without an official endorsement from the party?  Are there any historical examples of this sort of thing?

Comment: To addess the close vote: I am not asking for anyone's opinion about whether this is "right or wrong", I am asking about barriers to doing this thing.  For example, there might be trademark problems, or various jurisdictions may have laws about this.

Comment: Also, if there are historical examples of individuals running as, say, a Whig without having an endorsement from the official Whig party, I don't see how such citations might be opinion-based.

Comment: It is possible that this is marked "opinion-based" because the mere mention of the name "Donald Trump" tends to incite strong opinions?  This was merely an example.  I am happy to invent another hypothetical to illustrate my question.

Comment: There are no rules for claiming party membership and there is no one rule about getting on the ballot as another party if you lose a primary and in some cases it is against the rules.

Comment: @JoeW you wouldn't happen to have more specific info about or citations for these rules?  If so, I would upvote such an answer.

Comment: I don't have the rules for all 50 states + DC on what it takes to get on the ballot for a party or what happens if you lose a primary, that can be a very long answer. And honestly what you might see as a limitation others might not

Comment: @JoeW do the rules for this vary significantly by state?  For example, does there exist a single state where both JoeW and JoeB could be on the ballot for president as a "Democrat"?

Comment: @JoeW would Politics.SE be more receptive to this question if I changed the word "limitations" to "laws"?  I meant to include, say, bureaucratic red tape, but I am happy to restrict my question if needed.

Comment: The rules are up to each state and party when it comes to the primary and getting on the ballot with or without party support not to mention what happens if you lose the primary.

Comment: @JoeW there may be no rules for party membership, and ballot access is indeed a state matter, but both major parties have a large nominating convention to select a candidate for the presidency.  If a party selects Alice as their nominee, are there restrictions on Bob, while running as an independent, claiming to represent the true interests of that party or otherwise using or invoking the party's name or platform?  It's a good question.  For that matter, could the candidate start a new party with a similar name, such as "New York Republican Party" instead of "Republican Party of New York"?

Comment: @phoog That is incorrect there are plenty of states where someone who looses the primary can turn around and run as an independent. Also there is nothing stopping them from claiming to represent the interests of a party better then the party nominee. Sure there are some areas that prevent you from running if you have lost a primary but that isn't true everywhere.

Comment: @JoeW what is incorrect?  The only statements in my comment that aren't conceding -- and repeating -- statements that you made are "both major parties have a large nominating convention to select a candidate for the presidency" and "it's a good question."  Surely you don't dispute the first, and the second is a subjective opinion.  The rest of the comment consists only of questions.  So I don't understand what you think is incorrect.

Comment: @phoog You are correct that both parties do have a nomination process for this but that doesn't stop someone who loses out on the primary from getting on the ballot with another party (or independent) and still making the claim that they are the only real candidate for the party that they lost the primary. There are some states that have laws preventing that but the problem still is that in some states a primary loser can still run in the race and claim to be from the party but not on the party ticket.

Answer (score 3):

> Can a candidate run as a party X candidate without an official endorsement from the party?

No, because it is the party rather than the candidate that gives official endorsement. A losing primary candidate from party X for president could however theoretically claim to be an independent or win in some other party's primary (or gain endorsement by some other party in some other way) in all but two states, [South Dakota and Texas](https://ballotpedia.org/Sore_loser_laws_for_presidential_candidates,_2016).

All but three states have some kind of [sore loser law](https://ballotpedia.org/When_states_adopted_sore_loser_laws) that precludes a party switch for some elections between losing a primary and the general election. However, all but South Dakota and Texas have clarified their sore loser laws to state that they do not apply to presidential elections.

It is the national party rather than the state that decides who gets to carry that party's label during a presidential election. I do not know what would happen if someone ran for president in party X's primary in South Dakota or Texas, switched to party Y, and then won enough primaries to win that party's convention.

Comment: "It is the national party rather than the state that decides who gets to carry that party's label during a presidential election": how or where is this rule established?  What prevents a state party from putting Alice on the ballot despite the national party having nominated Bob?  My guess is that this is solely an internal matter of party discipline.  If that is correct, then a rogue candidate not endorsed by a party would not be subject to this discipline, so it wouldn't apply to the circumstances in question.  What stops Carol in this situation from claiming to represent the "true" party?

Comment: What reasons are there for sore loser laws. Like apart from messing with the ballot creation which could be fixed by a registration date, there doesn't seem to be a good reason for them to exist and they sound pretty anti-democratic to be honest.

Comment: @phoog The conditions by which a person can be listed as a candidate for a national office are set by individual states. Each state has its own laws, but they typically involve deferring to the parties. Individual candidates cannot list themselves as running as a party's candidate unless the party approves. State laws are written by politicians, who are for the most part are members of one of the two dominant parties. The laws protect the dominant parties. In some states it is very hard for a third party candidate to get on the ballot. (continued)

Comment: What stops Carol from being listed on some state's ballot in preference to Bob is that the state party needs support (lots of support) from the national party. The country hasn't seen a party implode in modern times. Parties have imploded in the past, and things tended not to work out well for the imploding party.

Comment: @haxor789 The laws were written by state legislatures, which are close to 100% Democrat or Republican. Each of the dominant parties work hard protect themselves (i.e., gerrymandering), and occasionally, work jointly to protect one other. These laws are one of the many reasons for why there is a two party system in the US.

Comment: @DavidHammen but the question is about prohibitions on claiming to represent a party's purportedly true ideology, not about being officially listed on the ballot as a candidate for that party.  Whether this is as a third-party candidate or otherwise, can a candidate who failed to obtain the nomination of the Republican party (or the Communist party for that matter) make statements such as "the party's nominee is not a true Republican (or Communist)" or "I'm the only true Republican (or Communist) in this race."

Comment: @phoog Not an expert on the U.S. in particular but probably yes. First of all political terms such as democrat, republican, communist, etc. are descriptions of ideologies beyond being party names so it's impossible to exclusively claim them or at least it should be and it's actually pretty likely for 2 candidates of a platform to split and still both claim the core values of that party. So you can't prevent that and that's ok. However you'd still have to denote that you're running for a different party/independent anything else would be fraud or at least in the gray area around it.

Comment: @haxor789 but "democrat" and "republican" have specific meanings that are not closely related to the parties' platforms or ideologies.  By this I mean, for example, that Republicans are not focused on avoiding monarchy (unlike republicans in monarchies).  So I think the question is about whether or to that extent there is legal protection of those names when used to denote the parties' platforms or ideologies.  Focusing on the mechanics of choosing a party's real candidate misses the point of the question.

Comment: @phoog Party names always have or at least had meaning when they were created so if someone passes the rather low bar of being pro-republic/democracy in a democratic republic, he'd have a legit claim to that name, maybe even a stronger claim than the actual named party or what if 2 political parties form around the same topic? You probably can't prevent them from choosing similar names and claiming they are the real representatives of a cause, but you could and should enforce unique identifiers of party membership so idk "I'm the real republican candiate" (-xxx, Independent) or whatnot.

Comment: @phoog The point is that you're in some kind of dilemma because political terms should be subject to free speech and you should not be able to censor, confuse or prevent representation by blocking them, so you need to tolerate the ambiguity in that regard. On the other hand party names should be unambiguous as you should know for whom you are voting, how they align. So you probably can't prevent the usage of the word but on any official document it would need to be clear that the candidate is not actually affiliated with a party.